# Python 2 Syntax error when executing print in boolean expression

Tags: python, python-2.x, short-circuiting

In order to demonstrate that python performs short-circuiting I tried to run the following code snipplet

```py
True or print('here')
```

and expected the code to execute, evaluate to `True` and not print `"here"`. However, python 2.7 reports a syntax error:

```sh
python2 -c "True or print('hier')"
  File "<string>", line 1
    True or print('hier')
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python3 behaves as I would have expected.
If I replace "print" with another function Python2.7 also behaves as expected.

Is this a bug in Python2.7 because of the support of the special syntax

```
print 'stuff'
```

or is this intended behavior? When the print statement comes as the first "condition", the code executes correctly in Python2.7 aswell.

Python version: Python 2.7.18

Comment: `print('here')` is not an expression in Python 2: it doesn't have a value so you can't use it as an operand.

Comment: `print` is a statement in Python 2.x, not an expression, so you can't short-circuit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement. As such it cannot appear on the right hand side of a binary operator like `or` where an expression is expected.

If you write `print('here') or True` it is parsed as the statement `print ('here' or True)` in Python 2 (which will print 'here'), not as the expression `(print('here')) or (True)` (which evaluates to `True` and prints 'here' as a side effect) as in Python 3.

Comment: Ah that is very interesting :). Thanks for adressing the `print('') or True` aswell. This explaination is consistent with the fact that `(print('here')) or True` raises a SyntaxError in python2 aswell